# chmod don't work in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I'm trying change permissions for all pastes inside a paste named "directory", with the command line 'chmod', Linux. The code that i'm using is the follow:

> chmod -R 777 /directory/*

But it's not working. The some pastes works fine, others not.

I try +rwxrwxrwx; su chmod; and don't work...

Comment: Do you have rights to do such `chmod`?

Comment: Did you mean to say you tried `sudo chmod`? `su chmod` says you want to **become the _user_** "chmod"...

Comment: You can only change the permissions of your own files (unless you are root).  Maybe those on which it works are your files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which OS do you use?
It's possible that you are niether the owner of the file nor have root permissions.
Have you tried to use sudo chmod once?
Are your files local or on some ftp/other server?
Do the files that dont work have anything in common?

You should maybe ask the question on askubuntu (in case you use ubuntu) or on any other linux forum.